# How to export a constant in react functional component

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, constants, export

```
import { StarIcon } from '@heroicons/react/solid'
import NumberFormat from 'react-number-format';
import Image from 'next/image'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { removeFromBasket, selectTotal } from '../slices/basketSlice'
import { useState } from 'react';

function CheckoutProduct({ id, title, price, rating, description, category, image, hasPrime }) {
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(useSelector(selectTotal))
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const addItemToBasket = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
    const product = {id, title, price, rating, description, category, image, hasPrime}
    setTotal(total + product.price)  

  }

  const removeItemFromBasket = () => {
    dispatch(removeFromBasket({ id }))
    
  }

  const removeNumber = () => {
    const product = {id, title, price, rating, description, category, image, hasPrime}
    if (count < 2) {
      dispatch(removeFromBasket({ id }))
    } else{
    setCount(count - 1)
    setTotal(total - product.price)
    }
  }
 
  return (
      <div className='flex flex-col space-y-2 m-auto justify-content-end  '>
            <div className='flex items-center'>
              <button onClick={addItemToBasket} className='button mr-auto'>+</button>
              <span className='p-2'>{count}</span>
              <button onClick={removeNumber} className='button ml-auto'>-</button>
            </div>
            <button className='button' onClick={removeItemFromBasket}>Remove From Cart</button>
          </div>
  )
}

export default CheckoutProduct
```

This is my code and I want to export the constant total from the State - const [total, setTotal] = useState(useSelector(selectTotal)) so that I can use this value in some other file. This is a redux constant.

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: You can user context API to share variables across files.

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: thanks.. will read the docs and report back

Comment: Maintain the value in redux, not as local state in the component. This is the way to access it in other files since you're already using redux. Context API is not the right approach.

Comment: Select Total is already a  part of redux - export const selectTotal = (state) => state.basket.items.reduce((total, item) => total + item.price, 0)

Comment: I have set the value in a state, does it cause an error?

Answer (score 0):

React has a unidirectional flow of data and sharing data among components is achieved with composition and inheritance only, unless a state management library like Redux is introduced.

Exporting the constant `total` cannot be achieved because its scope is limited to the component's closure. Export and Import keywords are used in ESM and work on modules.

However, the state can be passed down to all children components using props which are immutable.

[Composition and Inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)